# How to reverse ansible role installation ? (how to uninstall a role)

Tags: ansible

I've installed a role on my server.
now I want to remove it.
What is the right command to do this ?

for example:

```
  roles:
    - role: lean_delivery.java
    - role: lean_delivery.solr_standalone
```

how can I remove the lean_delivery.java role ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to understand here is, that ansible is not a package manager. You are not "installing" a role on a server that you can remove again, like you install and remove packages using apt, for example.
When using ansible, you define a state in your configuration (roles, playbooks etc.) and ansible takes care that the machine will have that state later. It does not record the changes it did so it can undo them later. (That is just not possible, if you include custom scripts, for example).
So to revert changes, you need to define the state that your machine had before you ran the playbook so ansible can create that state.
That can be quite easy, as for lot of modules, you can specify `state: absent` (e.g. files, installed packages) that will remove things that were added. But it can be very hard, as well, if you have custom scripts that ran on the original role, you need to write a script that reverts all changes the original script made on the system.
But what you need to undo depends on what you are doing in those roles.

Comment: basically you're saying it's up to the role  ? if they defined that state it will work and if not - than only manual remove ?

Comment: Well, yes and no. Theoretically, the role can include an option that will run the tasks to undo what has been done before. But I have never seen anybody doing that. I don't do it either, as it will usually be extremely difficult. You can have a look at the role's code and see if you can write an undo-role or playbook yourself.